# Failed to unpack with zip: expected 2, got 1

Tags: python, zip, unpack

This my code:

```
for i, j in zip((roll_number, stu_name)):
   print(i,j)
```

The error that I get :

```
Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have redundant () in the:

```
zip((roll_number, stu_name))
```

change to:

```
zip(roll_number, stu_name)
```

Here is the code:

```
for i, j in zip(roll_number, stu_name):
    print(i,j)
```